# Is the variable inside a block still visible outside the block?

Tags: python

I am new to python and suddenly was surprised seeing that a variable is still visible outside the block in which it's declared and assigned. The code is below:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    text = file.readlines()
    # and when do I close the file?

for i in range(len(text)):  # still can access the text even after the block.
    print(text[i])
```

How is this possible for the variable to be seen from outside the block?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be accessible? The context manager closes the file, but would you be surprised if some variable defined in an `if` block was accessible outside of it?

Comment: The variable is declared when it enters that block and is accessible outside. There is no need to close the file while using 'with open() as file'.

Comment: Python doesn't really have blocks. It certainly doesn't have block *scope*. The only scoping unit in Python is the named function (and `exec` (i.e. string eval) for some reason).

Comment: Python doesn't have variable declarations. What you have in your `with` block is simple assignment.

Comment: roganjosh and sk_353 much appreciated. it answer my question.

Comment: @roganjosh Many languages including C enforce block scoping. If you came from a C background, you would be very surprised to see this work.

Comment: @Michael fair observation :) Also, a perfectly legitimate response for the OP to have made for my question; it was not intended to show them up. It's ultimately my knowledge limitation on block scoping.

Comment: @Michael C has variable declarations, though. Simply assigning to a variable in a block doesn't limit its scope in C either.

Comment: @roganjosh not a shot at you, I assumed you came from a python heavy background :)

Comment: @Michael you assumed correctly :) I also didn't take it as a shot at me, just wanted to clarify my initial question to the OP. I'm not the downvoter and always curious to understand the logic of the OP if it mismatches my own

Comment: @melpomene If you declare the variable inside the block its scope will be limited to the block `if (condition) { int i = 5; } if (i == 5) { /*stuff*/} // 'i' undeclared` versus `int i; if (condition) { i = 5; } if (i == 5) { /*stuff*/} // all good` (Apologies for the messiness, comments are limiting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't have block scoping, it has function scoping for clarity but it doesn't enforce any scoping within a function.

With blocks implicitly call `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods and will close the file when you leave them, but in this case you're accessing the `text` variable which contains a list of lines not the file.

The real issue with code like this occurs if the block isn't entered and you reference a variable that doesn't exist yet.

```
x = False
if x:
    y = True
if y:   # NameError: name 'y' is not defined
    print ('yay')
```

versus

```
x = False
y = False
if x:
    y = True
if y:   # all good
    print ('yay')
```

Comment: you made it all very clear. Thank you!